# If $y=y(x)$ and $\frac{2+\sin x}{y+1}(\frac{dy}{dx})=-\cos x,y(0)=1,$ then $y(\frac\pi2)=$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> If $y=y(x)$ and $\dfrac{2+\sin x}{y+1}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=-\cos x,y(0)=1,$ then $y(\frac\pi2)=$

**My solution:**$$\frac{dy}{y+1}=-\frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}dx\\\implies\ln|y+1|=-\ln(2+\sin x)+\ln c\\\implies|y+1|=\frac{c}{2+\sin x}$$$y(0)=1\implies c=4.$ And putting $x=\frac\pi2,$ we get, $|y+1|=\frac43\implies y=\frac13,-\frac73$

Are both the answers acceptable? The answer given in the book is only $y(\frac\pi2)=\frac13$.

Comment: Ninad Munshi’s answer is right. The reason you get a false solution is basically that the absolute value in $|y+1|$ can mask discontinuities in $y$, so you can’t detect if $y$ jumps between the two branches so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the denominator $2+\sin x$ is always positive, the absolute value can be absorbed into the $c$

$$y + 1 = \frac{c}{2+\sin x}$$

$y(0) = 1$ fixes the branch of the function to be the positive branch, so there is only one answer.